# Display values from Javascript array in specific order depending on a key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

PFB the javascript code I have tried so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/mL6o4fyx/

I want to display values from below Javascript array in 12 boxes as shown in attached image Boxes. The product name from the object which have key value pair as "name": "Box" should be displayed in Box1. Also other products which have same position should be displayed in Box1. Eg. in the below array "name": "Box" present in id 100 have position: 8. The product from id 102 also have position 8. So both box1 and product9 should be displayed in Box1.

Once we get the position for box one, other products with next position should be displayed in next box. Eg. product 1,2,3 and 4 should be displayed in box2 since they all have position 9.

The position can be between 0 and 11. So if the position reaches 11, it should again start with 0.
If a product for any position is missing that box will remain blank.

```js
"product_positions": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Product1",
        "position": 9,
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product2",
        "position": 9,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Product3",
        "position": 9,
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Product4",
        "position": 9,
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Product5",
        "position": 10,
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Product6",
        "position": 7,
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Product7",
        "position": 6,
      },
      {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Box",
        "position": 8,
      },
      {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "Product8",
        "position": 2,
      },
      {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "Product9",
        "position": 8,
      }
    ],
```

These are the boxes I have so far:
[image: Boxes]

The final image should look like like this:

[image: Final-Boxes]

Comment: Please also provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Building the layout? Getting the data into the layout?

Comment: How is the visualization you call "boxes" implemented: in a HTML table?

Comment: The description of your task seems to throw yourself into considerable confusion. What do you think: by what kind of magic could we know more about it than you?

Comment: @johannchopin I have created the layout in html. I have written for loop to loop through product_positions array. I will share the code after sometime.

Comment: @DBS Problem is getting data into the layout. I have already generated the layout.

Comment: @Wolf The boxes are implemented using SVG. I have the layout already in place. I need to just insert data in it. I tried some javascript code, but the requirement is quite complex. So posted the question here to get some expert help.

Comment: In that case, we need to see your layout so far (Included in a snippet), and preferably also whatever you have tried so far to include the data.

Comment: @johannchopin PFB the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mL6o4fyx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

```js
var firstBox = '';
var secondBox = '';
var thirdBox = '';
var fourth = '';
var fifthbox = '';
var sixthbox = '';
var seventhbox = '';
var eigthbox = '';
var ninthbox = '';
var tenthbox = '';
var eleventhbox = '';
var twelthbox = '';
var box1 = [];
var box2 = [];
var box3 = [];
var box4 = [];
var box5 = [];
var box6 = [];
var box7 = [];
var box8 = [];
var box9 = [];
var box10 = [];
var box11 = [];
var box12 = [];
var boxnumber = [];
            
var product_positions= [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Product1",
    "position": 9,
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product2",
    "position": 9,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product3",
    "position": 9,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Product4",
    "position": 9,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Product5",
    "position": 10,
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Product6",
    "position": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Product7",
    "position": 6,
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "Box",
    "position": 8,
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "name": "Product8",
    "position": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "name": "Product9",
    "position": 8,
  }
];

let position = '';
let positionObj = product_positions.find(prod => prod.name === 'Box');
position = positionObj.position;       
console.log("position at line 82", position);
    
for (let products in product_positions){
  if (product_positions[products].position === position){
    box1.push(product_positions[products]); 
    console.log("box1", box1);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+1)%12)){
    box2.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box2", box2);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+2)%12)){
    box3.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box3", box3);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+3)%12)){
    box4.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box4", box4);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+4)%12)){
    box5.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box5", box5);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+5)%12)){
    box6.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box6", box6);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+6)%12)){
    box7.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box7", box7);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+7)%12)){
    box8.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box8", box8);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+8)%12)){
    box9.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box9", box9);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+9)%12)){
    box11.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box10", box10);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+10)%12)){
    box11.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box11", box11);
  }
  if (product_positions[products].position === ((position+11)%12)){
    box12.push(product_positions[products]);
    console.log("box12", box12);
  }
}
```